# Laravel 8 Migrate:rollback and migrate error

Tags: php, laravel, migration

While I run `php artisan:fresh`. It rollback all the table in my database and the I run php artisan migrate it will show the error:

> ```
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `online`.`appointps` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `appointps` add constraint `appointps_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)
> ```

Comment: Please share your migration file

Answer (score 0):

It seems the program trying to find foreign key (user_id).

Run the command: `php artisan migrate:refresh` to drop and migrate all tables.

***Warning: This command will drop all tables in DB and re-create them. Use this command only if you are in a test DB.***

Answer (score 0):

check if the format of `foreign key`  like the following example

```
    Schema::create('appointps', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->id();
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**note**: check the migration of `users` execute before `appointps`

hopefully that help you